# Change Proxy With vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, proxy, registry

I'm running into a little problem when i'm trying to change the proxy settings trough registry .

1. **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet`** Settings : **`ProxyEnable`** i mofidy this into **`1`**
2. **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet`** Settings : **`ProxyServer`** i modify this into **`ip:port`**

The problem is that until i access "ms-settings:network-proxy" or "LAN Settins" from "connections" from internet properties.. the change wouldn't take effect.
I told myself : Let's try and open "ms-settings:network-proxy"  hidden :

```
Dim ascuns As New ProcessStartInfo("ms-settings:network-proxy")
ascuns.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Process.Start(ascuns)
```

But it won't start hidden .. It starts just normal. 
Now you could help me start "ms-settings:network-proxy" hidden or you could show me a way around. Whatever it is, please help !

Answer (score 0):

To apply change in registry for enable and disable the proxy in Internet Explorer from VB.Net you have Two way.

**First way:**
1- Terminate Internet Explorer before change your registry.

```
 Shell("cmd.exe /c Taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe", AppWinStyle.Hide)
```

2- change the proxy enable or disable from registry as you did in your question.

**Second Way :**

1- Change proxy enable/disable as you did in your question
2- Terminate the windows Explorer and then Reopen after you change registry Already

```
Shell("cmd.exe /c Taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe && start /w /b explorer.exe", AppWinStyle.Hide)
```